# Navigating Lua class hierarchy with tolua++

Tags: lua, tolua++

I need to navigate, in Lua, the metatable hierarchy that represents a C++ class hierarchy bound from tolua++.

For example, say I have a class CFoo in C++, that has been bound by tolua++. In Lua, I can create an instance of this class (which becomes a userdata type) as follows:

```
local s = CFoo.new()
```

I can get hold of the metatable with:

```
local mt = getmetatable(s)
```

I can inspect the bound members of this class as follows:

```
for i,v in pairs(mt[".get"]) do
    -- Blah...
end
```

However, mt[".get"] contains only the members that were bound explicitly in this class, not the members bound in any parent classes. I need to traverse ALL bound members, including those in parent classes.

From inspecting the tolua++ source code, it seems that tolua++ holds superclass information in the "tolua_super" global table. But it's not clear how to navigate this from the Lua side.